# Exception on ActiveMQ: org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory

Tags: java, mule, activemq-classic

I am newbie in Mule and trying to make a simple application using ActiveMQ. I was following youtube tutorial and got the following exception.

```
Root Exception was: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory. Type: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
ERROR 2017-11-02 09:42:03,621 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,626 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Disposing app 'queue2file'                               +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,627 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Stopping flow: queue2fileFlow
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,627 [main] org.mule.transport.jms.activemq.ActiveMQJmsConnector: Removing listener on endpointUri: jms://file
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,630 [main] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Stopping service: queue2fileFlow.stage1
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,632 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,635 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping connector: Active_MQ1
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,635 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping connector: connector.file.mule.default
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,637 [main] org.mule.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Stopping ResourceManager
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,637 [main] org.mule.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Stopped ResourceManager
ERROR 2017-11-02 09:42:03,646 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: Failed to stop Mule context
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "stop" on object: com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase@307e4c44
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:243) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.stop(DefaultMuleContext.java:413) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.dispose(DefaultMuleContext.java:426) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.doDispose(DefaultMuleApplication.java:439) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.dispose(DefaultMuleApplication.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$1.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:41) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:137) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.dispose(ArtifactWrapper.java:36) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:77) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:536) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:333) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:193) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:282) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:566) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:283) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:139) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:33) ~[tooling-support-3.9.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.stop(ThrottlingPhase.java:370) ~[mule-module-throttling-ee-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    ... 33 more
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,647 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,648 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Disposing flow: queue2fileFlow
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,649 [main] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Disposing service: queue2fileFlow.stage1
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,650 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,656 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: Active_MQ
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,656 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: Active_MQ1
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,657 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: connector.file.mule.default
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,759 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Closing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@54709809: startup date [Thu Nov 02 09:42:00 BDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2017-11-02 09:42:03,774 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: 
**********************************************************************
* Application "queue2file" shut down normally on: 11/2/17 9:42 AM    *
* Up for: 0 days, 0 hours, 0 mins, 0.175 sec                         *
**********************************************************************
ERROR 2017-11-02 09:42:03,848 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'queue2file', see below        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:178) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:106) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:137) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:101) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:73) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:536) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:333) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:193) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:282) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:566) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:283) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:139) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:33) ~[tooling-support-3.9.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.mule.retry.RetryPolicyExhaustedException: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1658) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:483) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:449) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:320) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:146) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnectionFactory(JmsConnector.java:339) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnection(JmsConnector.java:435) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.doConnect(JmsConnector.java:555) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connectConnectorAndReceivers(AbstractConnector.java:1664) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1630) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1658) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:483) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:449) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:320) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:146) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:340) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:236) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:527) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:505) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.activemq.ActiveMQJmsConnector.getDefaultConnectionFactory(ActiveMQJmsConnector.java:47) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnectionFactory(JmsConnector.java:335) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnection(JmsConnector.java:435) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.doConnect(JmsConnector.java:555) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connectConnectorAndReceivers(AbstractConnector.java:1664) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1630) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1658) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:483) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:449) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:320) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:146) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    ... 19 more
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

I have also prepared a github project for reproducing the error.

**Github Project Link:** https://github.com/rizvi/queue2file

**Youtube Video Link:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldWUiPXsVc0

Comment: Please don't link to external tutorials. Post the relevant snippet here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sir, I have added relevant code snippet. Please let me know if any type of update is required.

Comment: Yeah, please move the necessary files from your github link into your question. We shouldn't have to visit external links to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For Maven Users,

If your application is mavenized, then go to POM file and add the following dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.5</version>
 </dependency>
```

### For gradle users,

If your application is gradlized, then go to **build.gradle** and add the following dependency:

> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all
>
> compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-all', version: '5.14.5'

### For Others,

If your application is not mavenized, then

> 1. Right click on your project
> 2. click on `Properties` and in the properties window,
> 3. click/select `Java Build Path` and select the tab `Libraries` and
> 4. click on the button `Add external JARS..` and
> 5. select file `activemq-all-x.xx.x,jar`

which will be available in the root folder of the apache-activemq folder.

### Resource Link:

1. [Resolve ActiveMQConnectionFactory class not found exception](http://www.tips.sentientmindz.com/2016/09/04/activemqconnectionfactorycnf/)
2. https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/38918/week-5-exception-on-activemq-could-you-please-help.html